# Is flutter tiktok SDK outdated?

Tags: flutter, oauth, tiktok

I integrated the tiktok sdk in my flutter project some times ago and it worked and for the past few weeks now when I try in my app it says "user not found". Looking around it seems that tiktok changed from oauth to oauthv2, and I feel like this package https://pub.dev/packages/tiktok_login_flutter has not been updated?
Is there another way to integrate it please?

Comment: It is NOT an official SDK provided by TikTok, beware to use it at your own risk. You will probably get an answer if asking on their [Github](https://github.com/Raiinmaker/tiktok_login_flutter/issues) project.